# How to fit off axis 2D Lorentzian Distribution

Tags: fitting, distributions

I have a 2D dataset. I can easily fit an on axis Lorentzian by assuming the independence of the x and y coordinates. In the case where no such assumption can be made, what method should I use to fit 2D Lorentzian distributed data?

Note, I am restricted to using mathematica in this project. I am wondering what sorts of tools are available in mathematica to perform this task.

Comment: I am asking how to do it with mathematica. Perhaps I should have stated that.

Comment: What bivariate probability density function are you considering?  (And not being a physicist I don't know what "off axis" and "on axis" means.)  ${1 \over {2\pi}} [{\gamma \over {((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+\gamma^2)^{1.5}}}]$ ?

Comment: @Kuba I think that link deals with regression-type issues rather than fitting probability distributions (assuming that the question above is actually dealing with estimating parameters from a bivariate probability distribution).  But I agree:  supply some data would go a long way to help define the need.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Just in the simpliest way--not in line with the xy-axis. Yes that distribution function is appropriate. I've tried using it, but using it with nonlinear fit appears to end up in a local minimum.

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` is for regression problems not for fitting distributions.  (Unless the desired relationship in the regression problem has the same shape as a probability density function - but even then the available error structures currently in *Mathematica* are not usually appropriate.)  I'll enter an answer for your consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose your two variables have marginal Cauchy (if you're a statistician) or a Lorentzian (if you're a physicist) distributions but are "correlated" (which is a loose term for "not independent").  Consider a `CopulaDistribution` which joins two marginal distributions and imposes some form of non-independence:

```
d = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM", α},
   {CauchyDistribution[a1, b1], CauchyDistribution[a2, b2]}]
```

Take a random sample from that distribution:

```
parms = {a1 -> 1, a2 -> 3, b1 -> 1, b2 -> 4, α -> 1/2};
sample = RandomVariate[d /. parms, 100];
```

Find maximum likelihood estimators of the 5 parameters:

```
FindMaximum[{LogLikelihood[d, sample], 
  b1 > 0 && b2 > 0 && 0 <= α <= 1}, {{a1, 1}, {b1, 1}, {a2, 3}, {b2, 4}, {α, 1/2}}]
(* {-642.961757205368, {a1 -> 1.167266125882441, b1 -> 1.1267968189006063,
  a2 -> 3.4697597908386792, b2 -> 3.4687845216307216, α -> .4876710819301035}} *)
```

***Update***

It is important to have good starting values but unlike the above example, one doesn't know the true values and must obtain starting values from the data.  For this maximum likelihood estimation one can use the sample medians for `a1` and `a2` and the semi-interquartile range for `b1` and `b2`.  I really have no good idea in finding a good starting value for $\alpha$.  It could start at 0 (implying idependence) or below I've used a completely arbitrary and little tested starting value for $\alpha$:  the square root of the Spearman's rho statistic.  (Your mileage may vary.)

```
αInit = SpearmanRho[sample[[All, 1]], sample[[All, 2]]]
αInit = Sign[αInit] Abs[αInit]^0.5
sol = FindMaximum[{LogLikelihood[d, sample], 
   b1 > 0 && b2 > 0 && -1 <= α <= 1},
  {{a1, Median[sample[[All, 1]]]}, {b1, InterquartileRange[sample[[All, 1]]]/2},
   {a2, Median[sample[[All, 2]]]}, {b2, InterquartileRange[sample[[All, 2]]]/2},
   {α, αInit}}]
```

Another important consideration is to obtain estimates of precision.  Here are the estimates of the asymptotic variances and covariances of the maximum likelihood estimators:

```
cov = -Inverse[(D[LogLikelihood[d, sample], {{a1, b1, a2, b2, α}, 2}]) /. sol[[2]]]
```

The correlation matrix can be found in the following manner:

```
cor = Table[cov[[i, j]]/(cov[[i, i]]^0.5 cov[[j, j]]^0.5), {i, 5}, {j, 5}]
```